# WatchKit App won't compile: “error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps” on only 1 of 2 machines

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an issue that has come up before however in this situation I have two development machines and the code build and runs on one machine but not on the other.

I have a MBP and a Mac Pro, the code is in git and once I have built on one machine and committed and pushed to git when the code is fetched on the other machine I receive the error message WatchKit App won't compile: “error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps”.

I have checked bundle identifiers and they all look correct which makes sense as it builds on one machine.

I also downloaded a sample app from Xamarin.com, the WatchTables demo.  The bundle identifiers are correct but I am receiving the same build error with that solution.

Any thoughts, I have checked the version of Mono and other frameworks on both machines, Xcode and VSfM are the same version and up to date.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading additional updates on the machine that was failing when I went to install and restart an error occurred and VSfM would no longer start.  So I reinstalled VSfM again, this allowed it to start and I was able to apply the updates.

Once I started the IDE again I was then able to build the solutions.

I would seem that something had become corrupt with VSfM and until the failure of the updates broke the IDE this wasn't getting sorted.

All is good now.